# Keep list elements with three or more on either side

Tags: python, list

How can we keep only elements that have three or more elements on either side? For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]  =>  [1, 4]
```

- The `1` has three elements on its right, so we keep it.
- The `2` and `3` each have only one or two elements on either side, so we remove them.
- The `4` has three elements on its left, so we keep it.

More examples:

```
[]  =>  []
[1]  =>  []
[1, 2]  =>  []
[1, 2, 3]  =>  []
[1, 2, 3, 4]  =>  [1, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  =>  [1, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  =>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  =>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Edit: Here's a bad way in case someone indeed minds that I didn't provide any "attempt":

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]

N = len(L)
for i in reversed(range(N)):
    left = i
    right = N - 1 - i
    if not (left >= 3 or right >= 3):
        L.pop(i)

print(L)
```

Comment: Because no attempts shown on a pretty basic question with 26k rep?

Comment: @Julien Hmm, I considered making up something intentionally bad, but I don't think it should be necessary.

Comment: @Julien Actually I was hoping my rep would work in *favor*, i.e., I thought people would realize that I'm of course capable of doing this and therefore have a different reason to share this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def f(L, n=3):
    L = L[:]
    del L[-n:n]
    return L

Ls = [
    [],
    [1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
]

for L in Ls:
    print(f(L))
```

Based on Julien's code for the test output.

Comment: Also has the bonus of being easily generalizable, if you don't mind the edit :) .

Comment: @Julien Yep, ok :)

Comment: @Julien The generalization works, but breaks my reasoning a bit. I'm thinking of it as "Delete elements that are in the last n (achieved by `-n:`) **and** in the first n (achieved by `:n`)". Which isn't quite right for n=0, as `-0:` doesn't mean "last zero" but means "all", i.e., rather the opposite.

Comment: I don't get your point. Are you saying it works except for 0, or that it still works for 0 but you just *think* it's non intuitive how it works in that case?

Comment: Yes `-0:` is all, but the first 0 elements `:0` is still none, so if you remove elements that are any *and* none, you still remove none...

Comment: @Julien Yes, that's why it still works. Only my reasoning as stated isn't quite right and needs that additional reasoning for n=0, which is annoying :-)

Answer (score 3):

Simply this?

```
def f(L):
    if len(L) < 4:
        return []
    elif len(L) == 4:
        return [L[0], L[3]]
    elif len(L) == 5:
        return [L[0], L[1], L[3], L[4]]
    else:
        return L

Ls = [
    [],
    [1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
]

for L in Ls:
    print(f(L))
```

Comment: That works, but is far more code than necessary. (And the inconsistency between returning a new object and returning the given one seems dangerous.)

Comment: If that's a concern add a copy in the last case... You didn't ask for most concise code. This is clear and simple, I personally prefer over potentially obscure one liners...

Comment: Ok... I wonder how obscure you'll find mine :-)

Comment: Michael found it. What do you think of it?

Comment: it's good too, I agree it's the best and should be accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

N = 3
out = [v for i, v in enumerate(lst) if N <= i or i < len(lst) - N]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This would be unnecessary slow for very long lists, where there is no need to iterate...